# Topological photon mass and QED in (2+1)-D

Tags: homework-and-exercises, mass, quantum-electrodynamics, topological-field-theory, propagator

**My question was:** how to compute topological photon mass in (2+1) QED and why it comes?

Comment: Are you asking about the mass term of the form $m \, \epsilon_{abc} \, A_a \, \partial_b A_c$ ?

Comment: @Kostas , yes, I asked about it. I believe that I have understood its appearence and have write the answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, let me say why photon obtain non-zero mass and how. It comes from one-loop correction to photon propagator, which is given by simple fermionic loop:
$$\Pi_{\mu\nu}(k)\propto \int\frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3}\frac{\mathrm{Tr}\left[\gamma^{\mu}(\gamma\cdot p+m)\gamma^{\nu}(\gamma\cdot(p+k)+m)\right]}{(p^2-m^2+i\epsilon)((p+k)^2-m^2+i\epsilon)}.$$
Trace plays the crucial role in this expression because in (2+1), we have
$$\mathrm{Tr}(\gamma^{\mu}\gamma^{\nu}\gamma^{\lambda})=-2i\epsilon^{\mu\nu\lambda}.$$
Therefore, we can write down polarization tensor as
$$\Pi_{\mu\nu}^{S}(k)+\Pi_{\mu\nu}^A(k).$$
One can try to use dimensional regularization to deal with this integral but I conjecture that does not work: dimensional regularization is insensitive to odd divergencies. Then, in my view, the best way to compute $\Pi_{\mu\nu}(k)$ is dispersion relation. For $\Pi^{S}_{\mu\nu}(k)$, I can quickly obtain the following expression for imaganiary part (I know answer for (3+1) and the only difference is the factor $\sqrt{k^2/4-m^2}$),
$$\mathrm{Im}\,\,\Pi^{S}\propto\frac{4m^2+k^2}{\sqrt{k^2}},$$
where I denote $\Pi^S(k)=g^{\mu\nu}\Pi_{\mu\nu}^S/2$ Then, to regularize the expression for $\Pi_{\mu\nu}^S(k)$, we use the following dispersion relation:
$$\Pi(t)\propto t^2\int_{4m^2}^{\infty}\frac{ds}{s(s-t)}\mathrm{Im}\,\,\Pi^{S}(s),\quad s=k^2,$$
but this part of polarization tensor is not interesting. The same calculations for assymetric part of vacuum polarization gives very similar answer for $\Pi^A(k)$ and the most important fact is
$$\boxed{\Pi^A(0)\propto\frac{e^2}{4\pi}\frac{m}{|m|}.}$$
Therefore, technically, photon mass appears due to assymetric contribution to vacuum polarization tensor. Physically, it comes from *parity anomaly* and I do not find the best words, but roughly speaking it means that mass term are invariant on $P$-transformations only in even dimensions and I have emphasized it by denotation $m/|m|$.

**Furthermore**, Coleman & Hill showed that higher order corrections are zero for *all possible* matter fields and couplings to electromagnetic field. In addition, the same effect arises in every *odd* dimensional QED theory.

**Finally**, photon obtains mass *without* any topological terms in initial lagrangian and one can roughly say that it is an analogue of chiral anomaly existing in *even* dimensions.

To be honest, I did not check all the calculations and therefore I use $\propto$ instead of $=$, but intermediate derivitions are the same.

This answer is based on the following papers:

1. Scharf, G., et al. "Causal approach to (2+ 1)-dimensional QED." Annals of Physics 231.1 (1994): 185-208, [link](https://doi.org/10.1006/aphy.1994.1039)
2. Coleman, Sidney, and Brian Hill. "No more corrections to the topological mass term in QED3." Physics Letters B 159.2-3 (1985): 184-188, [link](https://doi.org/10.1016/0370-2693(85)90883-4)